# Can Neural Network model use Weighted Mean (Sum) Squared Error as its loss function?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am nooby in this field of study and probably this is a pretty silly question. I want to build a normal ANN, but I am not sure if I can use a weighted mean square error as the loss function.
If we are not treating each sample equally, I mean we care the prediction precision more for some of the categories of the samples more than the others, then we want to form a weighted loss function. 
Lets say, we have a categorical feature `ci`, `i` is the index of the sample, and for simplicity, we assume that this feature takes binary value, either 0 or 1. So, we can form the loss function as

```
(ci + 1)(yi_hat - yi)^2

#and take the sum for all i
```

Are there going to be any problem with the back-propagation? I don't see any issue with calculating the gradient or updating the weights between layers.
And, if no issue, how can I program this loss function in Keras? Because it seems that the loss function only takes two parameters, `y_true` and `y_pred`, how can I plug in the vector `c`?

Comment: I feel like this has the potential to be a very good question - however this isn't going to be the best format for Stack Overflow. Can you show us the code you tried, and try to format the question. Right now it is a block of text that can be hard to follow each step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with that. Functions can declare the constants within themselves or even take the constants from an outside scope:

```
import keras.backend as K

c = K.constant([c1,c2,c3,c4,...,cn])

def weighted_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = keras.losses.get('mse')
    return c * loss(y_true,y_pred)
```

---

Exactly like yours:

```
def weighted_loss(y_true,y_pred):

    weighted = (c+1)*K.square(y_true-y_pred)
    return K.sum(weighted)
```

Comment: Many thanks! So, all constant has to be redefined using K.constant, and I cannot simply multiply a vector to a tensor.

Comment: Yes. You can use scalar python numbers, but not lists. (Not that I know).